# Date в Firefox. Как настроить

Tags: html, firefox, input

`<input type="date" id="ExampleDate">` Не работает в Firefox, я знаю почему. Собственно, вопрос: как это исправить? Календарь очень важен для моего сайта, с его помощью я получаю дату.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Так вы знаете, почему, или всё-таки не знаете?

Answer (score 7):

Все просто. `<input type='date' />` плохо [поддерживается браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#search=date), так что на него лучше не надеяться. Самым простым вариантом решения этой проблемы является уход от календаря в сторону трех `select`'ов под день, месяц и год. Либо использовать одно из множества готовых решений, [например](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_UI).

Между прочим, задача написания своего календаря на `JS` является так сказать, той программой, которую должен попробовать написать каждый `JS` программист.

Comment: Не знаю, почему вы решили, что каждый JS программист должен писать свой календарь... но в остальном `+`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, написание календаря не такое простое, как написание какого-либо калькулятора и может научить многим вещам. Например, делегации событий, создании анимации переходов, работе с объектом `Date` и работе с объектами вообще. При правильном подходе, это очень хорошее упражнение для начала.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться календарём на JavaScript. Например, [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) из jQueryUI.
Ещё можно посмотреть вариант [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10).