# HTML input type="date" в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html5, firefox, datetime

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему во всех браузерах `input type="date"` работает нормально, а в *Firefox* отображаются как обычный `input type="text"`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451780/date-%D0%B2-firefox-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C   таких тем полно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что Мозилловцы уже 3 года пытаются реализовать датно-временные импуты, и на данном этапе у них даже окончательной спецификации нету.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888320
Сейчас там страдают над тем, как переключать 12/24 часовые режимы,
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1069609 и судя по бактрекеру, ожидать реализации нужно не скоро.
А вообще вот удобный сайт для определения реализаций в разных браузерах.
http://caniuse.com/#search=Date%20and%20time%20input%20types